# mysql select only non canceled rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following data:

```
id  vote_id  user_id  status 
1   1        1        1         the vote is active 
2   1        1        2         vote is canceled 
3   1        1        1         vote is active again
```

status is always 1 at first, then if status is 2 the vote is canceled. On the third row the user acts again and its status is active. I need to be able to select a row only if it doesn't have a canceling row afterwards

Considering that I need to do this not only for 1 vote_id per user, how can I get all rows for all users that are still active!?

The full data sample will look like this:

```
id  vote_id  user_id  status 
1   1        1        1         - vote1 is active 
2   1        1        2         - vote1 is canceled 
3   1        1        1         - vote1 is active again 
4   2        1        1         - vote2 is active 
5   2        1        2         - vote2 is canceled
```

I would need only row 3 here because (1-2) and (4-5) cancel each other out.

Comment: Is (vote_id, user_id, status) a key in your table (ie. a user can have only one active vote with the same id)?

Comment: hello, Christina. Thats correct. Only 1 vote with vote_id x can be active. you can have many active votes with different vote_id's

Comment: add a date or time column and select the record where `id = what_you_need and date = latest`

Comment: thank you @baig772 .. this is a sample data. they do have dates. i can get the latest per 1 vote_id .. but if you need to have latest that is status 1 (and never canceled) for all vote_id's ... e.g. select all active votes

Comment: so what's the problem? when a user votes, it inserts the data with the current date? if yes then you can easily get your result

Comment: @baig772 Please give me an example because i've tried tons of queries and non worked

Comment: Also I can sort on id because higher id means the vote is most current. Still cant get what I need .. get All active votes that were not canceled in other rows after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the situation

```
id, vote_id, user_id, status 
1,1,1,1 - the vote is active 
2,1,1,2 - vote is canceled 
3,1,1,1 - vote is active again
```

I assume that the system does not allow for a vote to be canceled *unless* that vote is active, nor to reactivate unless it is in canceled state.

Therefore, if the number of "state 1"'s for a vote is equal to the number of "state 2"'s, the vote is canceled; otherwise it is active.

Under this hypothesis,

```
SELECT id, vote_id, user_id, active AS status FROM
    ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 WHEN status = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)
              AS active,
           user_id,
           vote_id
    FROM votes GROUP BY user_id, vote_id ) AS votes
WHERE votes.status = 1;
```

or also - I don't like this because of `status` name ambiguity -

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 WHEN status = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS status,
    user_id,
    vote_id
FROM votes GROUP BY user_id, vote_id
HAVING status = 1;
```

If you are sure of the status values, and there are no others, you could also try

```
SUM((1-status)*2+1) AS status
```

but I don't know if the speed gain (if any!) can make up for the lack of clarity.

Comment: You rock! the first query failed, but the second is doing the trick like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also all your assumptions were true!

Comment: Shucks. I had used 'active' and forgotten aliasing it back in the first query (*and I had even bragged about ambiguity! It serves me right*). Fixed. Needlessly, but fixed :-)

Comment: thank you so much for the support you ended a huge misery on my side :) never used pascal type of logic in my queries ...will do more and more when i have complex queries :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

```
select t.*
from @temp t
left join (select max(id) as lastCanceledId, vote_id
            from @temp
            where status = 2
            group by vote_id) cancels on t.vote_id = cancels.vote_id
where COALESCE(cancels.lastCanceledId, 0) < t.id
and t.Status = 1
```

where @temp is the name of your table.  The select in the middle finds the last canceled row for a given vote_id.  The outer part filters out all rows that came before the canceling row.  This assumes that the ids are indicative of the order things happened in.